# Modify the Fields on Related List

Tags: opportunity, page-layout, related-list, fields, lightning-record-page

I would just like to ask on how we can add more fields to display on Related List on the right-side?

I know that I can re-arrange them through Page Layout Editor, but my goal is to display 5-6 fields, rather than the default 4 fields on that component, and the additional fields would be under the Date field. Is this possible?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the related list in the narrow component section on the right of the lightning record page, there's a maximum of 4 fields that can be displayed.

If you were to use this in the wider container to the left, you can select "Enhanced List" which can show up to 10 columns (see below):

[image]

In saying this, you still need to add any column you require to the related list configuration on the page layout.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for noticing this, bhann! I figured this would be the case after searching for hours on where we can configure this.

BTW, do you happen to find this limitation documented anywhere? Would you mind sharing it if you do?

Comment: Hi @VanceSOQL, I didn't find any documentation per such, but here is a link to a video Salesforce released demoing this feature: https://admin.salesforce.com/blog/2019/maximize-your-lightning-pages-with-new-enhanced-related-lists

P.S. Please upvote my original answer if this helped you solve the issue :)